# Loading appointments to a non-default Outlook calendar from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I have a project to put employees leave schedules into a shared or global calendar.

The appointments save to my default calendar.

I have tried a few different approaches. This is the current approach:

```
Sub Create_Outlook_2()
' Create the Outlook session

Dim oApp As Object
Dim oNameSpace As Namespace
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim myApt As AppointmentItem

Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("000000007CF129E6C6BAA74F9B2AB399FABB280E01006EC36FFC70429B4EAE1875321A4609670078C4FA00320000").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

With oFolder
'    Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'    ' Set data collection to take from "Leave Table" sheet
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Sheets("Leave Table")
    ' Start looping at row 3 (first two rows are for readability)
    r = 3
    ' Do/while set condition
    Do Until Trim(wsSrc.Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
        ' Create event item
        Set myApt = oApp.CreateItem(1)
        ' Set the event properties
        ' Set Subject line of event
        With myApt
            .Subject = "Time Off " & wsSrc.Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & wsSrc.Cells(r, 2).Value
           ' Set start time
            .Start = DateValue(wsSrc.Cells(r, 3)) + wsSrc.Cells(r, 8).Value
           ' Set end time
            .End = DateValue(wsSrc.Cells(r, 3)) + wsSrc.Cells(r, 9).Value
           ' Turn reminders off
            .ReminderSet = False
           ' Set busy status to free
            .BusyStatus = 0
           ' Have the body of the event read as the decription from the leave form in Viewpoint
            .Body = wsSrc.Cells(r, 4).Value
           ' Save event in owners calendar
            .Save

        End With
       ' Move to next row
        r = r + 1
       ' Repeat do/while loop until condition is no longer valid
    Loop

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out:**

```
Sub Create_Outlook_2()

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Sheets("Leave Table")
    ' Start looping at row 3 (first two rows are for readability)
    r = 3
    ' Do/while set condition
    Do Until Trim(wsSrc.Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""

        ' Create the Outlook session
        Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
        ' Set the namespace
        Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        ' Set the folder the appointment will be created in.
        Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("Folder ID Number").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

        ' Set with block for the appointment configuration loop
        With oFolder
           ' Set Subject line of event
            .Subject = wsSrc.Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & wsSrc.Cells(r, 2).Value
           ' Set start time
            .Start = DateValue(wsSrc.Cells(r, 3)) + wsSrc.Cells(r, 8).Value
           ' Set end time
            .End = DateValue(wsSrc.Cells(r, 3)) + wsSrc.Cells(r, 9).Value
           ' Turn reminders off
            .ReminderSet = False
           ' Set busy status to free
            .BusyStatus = 0
           ' Have the body of the event read as the decription from the leave form in Viewpoint
            .Body = wsSrc.Cells(r, 4).Value
           ' Save event in owners calendar
            .Save
           ' End with block
        End With
       ' Move to next row
        r = r + 1
       ' Repeat do/while loop until condition is no longer valid
    Loop

End Sub
```

To get Folder ID #:

**With the calendar you want to create appointments in selected** (open it in a new window for good measure), press F11 to bring up Outlook macros and run the following code under "ThisOutlookSession":

```
Private Sub GetOutlookFolderID()
     'Determines the Folder ID of Folder
    Dim olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olfolder = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    olfolder.Display
    MsgBox (olfolder.EntryID)
    Set olfolder = Nothing
    Set olapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample spreadsheet - with fake names:

[image: SPREADSHEET I AM USING]

Answer (score 0):

There's an additional way to access the folder instead of getting the ID:

```
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.Folders.Item("account address").Folders.Item("Calendar").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```

Where "account address" is the email address of the account

Additionally, I'm working with multiple outlook.com calendars and found that you can do the following to access one of the non-default calendars:

```
Set oFolder = oNameSpace.Folders.Item("account address").Folders.Item("Calendar").Folders.Item("Other calendar name").Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```

Couldn't have done any of this without your post, Joshua.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create an appointment in Outlook, using Excel, run the script below.

```
Private Sub Add_Appointments_To_Outlook_Calendar()

    'Include Microsoft Outlook nn.nn Object Library from Tools -> References
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim Remind_Time As Double

    i = 2
    Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)

    'Loop through entire list of Reminders to be added
    While Subj <> ""
        Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        oAppt.Subject = Subj
        oAppt.Location = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        oAppt.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Remind_Time = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) * 1 * 60
        oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Remind_Time
        oAppt.AllDayEvent = True
        oAppt.Save

        i = i + 1
        Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    Wend
    MsgBox "Reminder(s) Added To Outlook Calendar"

End Sub
```

' The code comes from this link:
 http://officetricks.com/add-appointment-to-outlook-calendar-through-excel-macro-vba/

The script is run from Excel, and as such, you must set a reference to Outlook before you run the code.  Also, notice that the worksheet needs to be setup properly for the script to run.  It should look something like this.  Everything is read from Excel into Outlook.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had to find out a method to grasp the offered number by the `GetOutlookFolderID-Sub`, which is quite big. The solution proved to be very simple:

- Open in your VBE the Direct window.
- Replace in `Private Sub GetOutlookFolderID()` the line: `MsgBox (olfolder.EntryID)`
  by the line: `Debug.Print olfolder.EntryID`

and simply copy the number from the Direct window into the Set olfolder-statement.